# How to properly use Winston

Tags: node.js, winston

I have read the docs for logging in node.js using the winston package.

My question: Do I need to add my logging module to every single page that requires `logging..` or does winston somehow intercept `console.log` and `console.error`.

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, you'd need to require your logger in the modules that use it.

However, you can follow the suggestion made by [**@spmason**](https://github.com/spmason) in the gist [logging.js](https://gist.github.com/spmason/1670196) or what [**@fega**](https://github.com/fega) suggests in his [comment](https://gist.github.com/spmason/1670196#gistcomment-2189760) to redefine the properties of the `console` Object:

```js
console.log = (...args) => logger.info.call(logger, ...args);
console.info = (...args) => logger.info.call(logger, ...args);
console.warn = (...args) => logger.warn.call(logger, ...args);
console.error = (...args) => logger.error.call(logger, ...args);
console.debug = (...args) => logger.debug.call(logger, ...args);
```